# How break strong dependency with interface?

Tags: java, spring

At this moment, I'm studying how Spring can help in case of strong dependencies in java. When I mention different codes, I always found a schema as bellow. But I don't understand what is the purpose of this line

```
private IWriter writer;
```

Why is it written as a field of the class?

```
 public class Order {
    private IWriter writer;

    public IWriter getWriter() {
        return writer;
    }
    public void setWriter(IWriter writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }
    public void write() {
        this.writer.write(this.getState()); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, you can also use dependency injection as well

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your issue. Why not? How would _you_ write it?

Answer (score 1):

It's Dependency injection

You can read it on wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: use interface allows you to use different implementations of object

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit of using of interface is, It separates what the caller expects from the implementation. You have a pure set of methods you can call without any knowledge of the implementation. This separation means you don't need to know the class of any actual implementation.

Suppose There may exists multiple implementation of IWriter ie, JsonWriter, XMLWriter etc. but Order does not need to know about them. By using spring you can provide any implementation through configuration. Order will just know about IWriter and its methods. Calling them will call the implementation provided.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse Of Control pattern; using interface and making choice of implementation dynamic